# mod_rewrite all /something to index.html

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite all urls of the following pattern:
`http://example.com/csfdg/anything`
into `http://example.com/csfdg/index.html`

my .htaccess file at the root level contains this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \/csfdg\/.* /csfdg/index.html [L]
```

The checker at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ tells me that it would rewrite my URLs the way I want, but when I go to `http://example.com/csfdg/anything` I just get a 404. It's very hard to tell what's going on, but I know that the RewriteEngine is working because if I mess with it enough I can get 500 errors to happen :)

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to escape anything in a rule, and you don't need the initial slash. So use `csfdg/.*` instead. Better yet, use `^csfdg/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.html$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.+$ /$1/index.html [L]
```

RewriteConditon is important here to avoid rewriting **/foo/index.html** to itself.

Comment: Thanks, with a little bit more fiddling to exclude some resource directories that I needed to not rewrite this worked for me.